# fulluy vectorized slice-wise matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a 128X3X3 and a 128X3X5 3D NumPy matrices A and B respectively
I want to multiply each 3by3 slice of A by each 3by5 slice of B to have finally a matrix C of dimension 128X3X5.
all this for sure has to be fully vectorized and no loops are expected.
thanks!

Comment: Looks like dimensions match `matmul's`expectation.  `A@B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want the [matrix product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) (since you can't just directly multiply differently shaped matrices, in the way you put it). So you can use the `@` operator:

```
A@B
```

Or with [`np.matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html):

```
np.matmul(A, B)
```

Check:

```
A = np.random.random((128, 3, 3))
B = np.random.random((128, 3, 5))

(A@B).shape
#(128, 3, 5)
```